# Height is different in desktop and mobile even if I'm using pixels?

Tags: css, mobile

This is how it looks in desktop:

[image]

This is how it looks in mobile:

[image]

Relevant css:

styles.sass:

```
item
  .row
    cursor: pointer
    height: 297px
    .top-border
      border-top: 2px dotted $brand-four
      margin: 30px 0 40px
```

Live site:

http://alexandrochen.com/

(I'm using the [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) framework).

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pixels may be different sizes.

Some browsers also allow magnification of rendered elements to help the visually challenged so the sizes can be different.

Comment: I see, so what's the best way of solving this?

Comment: Don't use pixels.  Or, use some type of conditional CSS (shudder).

Comment: you are referring to media queries?

Comment: Media types.  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html  There is one called handheld.

Answer (score 1):

The pixel "physical" size on various devices depends on the pixel density (measured in pixel-per-inch or ppi) and the multiplier the device is using.

For example, MacBook Pro Retina 15" has 220 ppi, while the regular Macbook Pro has 110 ppi. But the OS is multiplying the pixel count internally by 2 in retina so the "physical" size of your item should be *similar*. But since retina is using twice the amount of pixels to render the same amount of data, bitmaps will look pixelated.

Check this out for more information on which device has what ppi: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density